# Laravel - Tela em branco

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

## O que eu preciso

Quero verificar se um projeto em branco do Laravel está funcionando corretamente no servidor de desenvolvimento, ou seja, só quero ver se pelo menos ele carrega a view, e depois vou fazendo alguns testes.

## O que eu fiz

Baixei e instalei o Laravel localmente, configurei o `app/path` em `config/app.php` e passei a pasta pro servidor. Ao acessar a pasta "public" eu recebi uma tela em branca, sem nenhum erro. Abaixo segue a troca de código que fiz no arquivo de rotas. Eu mudei pra ele jogar na tela um `Hello World` e deu certo.

**OBS**: Ele está funcionando normalmente em meu computador, chamando a view padrão do Laravel 5.

## O código testado

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

## O código padrão

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
```

### Config/App.php

```
'url' => 'http://endereco_do_servidor/pasta/pasta_meu_projeto/',
```

## Permissão na pasta

Só para informar: o projeto está da seguinte forma no servidor `http://endereco_do_servidor/pasta/pasta_meu_projeto/',`. Tenho o endereço ip do servidor de desenvolvimento, dentro dele existem 3 pastas com cada tipo de projeto, dentro de uma dessas pastas existem outras pastas, sendo cada uma para projetos distintos, e uma dessas é a do projeto que acabei de criar.

Fui informado que era preciso dar as permissões necessárias, então eu pedi para darem um chmod 775 para todas as pastas dentro dela.

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

Comment: Pode ser muitas coisas, seu servidor tem os [requisitos suficientes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#server-requirements)? Tente seguir as instruções da documentação, pois alterar o endereço da url no app/config só é relevante para comandos via console.

Comment: @gmsantos Dentro da pasta eu rodei o comando "find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;" para liberar as permissões.

Comment: E isso resolveu o problema?

Comment: Boas, ainda não percebi onde está a questão! Pelo que li está tudo a funcionar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tenho acesso direto ao servidor, mas fui informado do procedimento necessário para funcionamento. 
Ao fazer acesso aos arquivos de webserver, o Apache usa um login próprio, esse login não estava incluso no grupo do proprietário, por isso o comando 775 não funcionava, e sim o 777 (permitindo acesso e controle total por usuários externos). O usuário apache foi colocado no mesmo grupo do dono das pastas e foi voltada a permissão `find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;` para a pasta **storage**, deixando o **Apache** com plenas permissões, mas usuários externos com suas limitações.

Comment: Posso estar falando besteira, mas pensei que só as pastas de dados precisavam de permissão, mas não tenho experiencia com isto para ter certeza.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Apenas a pasta **storage** necessita da permissão.

Comment: É mais ou menos o que eu quis dizer, não entendi a necessidade do usuário "apache" no mesmo grupo.